# How to CREATE USER in MySQL from JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create account for user in `MySql` from `JdbcTemplate` with update method.
my query goes like this

```
String sqlStatement = "CREATE USER ?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?";
Object[] values = new Object[3];
-
--
```

I put required values in Value [] such as username , localhost and password. And I am sure I am putting values in values[].

I am executing this query as

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlStatement, values);
```

It gives me this error error.

---

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE USER ?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:95) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

---

I had grant all permission to User whom I using in connection.For confirmation, From workbench I can create users with same command .

In my connection URL I am using pc IP address like this : `jdbc:mysql://10.35.34.169:3306/mydb`

Comment: did you put single quotes around the values? otherwise try "CREATE USER '?'@'?' IDENTIFIED BY '?'";

Comment: I think that is handled by JdbcTemplate.

Comment: indeed, however, a brief look at the spec tells me you should be sending something more like jdbcTemplate.update(sqlStatement, user, host, pw)

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of using jdbcTemplate.update(...), use jdbcTemplate.execute(...) and pass the sql string as

> CREATE USER abdul123 IDENTIFIED BY 'abdul123'

i,e

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE USER abdul123 IDENTIFIED BY 'abdul123'");
```